# iotedge not starting after fresh deployment

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, azure-iot-edge, libvirt

I'm trying to start iotedge on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-158-generic x86_64)

The OS runs on kubevirt on a kubernetes cluster. 45 kubelets hosting iotedge 1.4.2 are humming along nicely.

I'm trying to deploy additional edgedevices via helm chart the same way as all exiting kublets.

The kubelet deploys and runs. I can sign in via SSH.

Running sudo iotedge list returns:

```
sudo iotedge list
A module runtime error occurred
caused by: A module runtime error occurred
caused by: error trying to connect: No such file or directory (os error 2)
caused by: No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

running sudo iotedge system status

```
sudo iotedge system status
System services:
    aziot-edged             Ready
    aziot-identityd         Ready
    aziot-keyd              Ready
    aziot-certd             Ready
    aziot-tpmd              Ready
```

running tail /var/log/syslog

```
tail /var/log/syslog
Feb 28 15:52:22 iotedgevm systemd[1]: Starting Azure IoT Certificates Service API socket.
Feb 28 15:52:22 iotedgevm systemd[1]: Listening on Azure IoT Certificates Service API socket.
Feb 28 15:52:22 iotedgevm systemd[1]: Starting Azure IoT TPM Service API socket.
Feb 28 15:52:22 iotedgevm systemd[1]: Listening on Azure IoT TPM Service API socket.
Feb 28 15:52:22 iotedgevm systemd[1]: Started Azure IoT Edge daemon.
Feb 28 15:52:22 iotedgevm aziot-edged[3827]: 2023-02-28T15:52:22Z [INFO] - Starting Azure IoT Edge Daemon
Feb 28 15:52:22 iotedgevm aziot-edged[3827]: 2023-02-28T15:52:22Z [INFO] - Version - 1.4.9
Feb 28 15:52:22 iotedgevm aziot-edged[3827]: 2023-02-28T15:52:22Z [ERR!] - Failed to load settings: could not read config
Feb 28 15:52:22 iotedgevm systemd[1]: aziot-edged.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=153/n/a
Feb 28 15:52:22 iotedgevm systemd[1]: aziot-edged.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

sudo iotedge config apply:

```
sudo iotedge config apply
Command failed: could not parse config file: TOML parse error at line 1, column 1
  |
1 | # ==============================================================================
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cloud_timeout_sec must be at least 70 seconds
```

hmmmm.....

the config.toml file looks ok to me and I even replaced it with one of my running edge devices. weird.

sudo ls /etc/aziot -l

```
sudo ls /etc/aziot -l
total 68
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Feb 28 15:02 certd
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 14005 Feb 28 15:02 config.toml
-rw------- 1 root root 18848 Dec  1  2020 config.toml.edge.template
-rw------- 1 root root 10185 Sep 16  2020 config.toml.template
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Feb 28 15:02 edged
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Feb 28 15:02 identityd
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Feb 28 15:02 keyd
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Feb 28 15:02 tpmd
```

permissions look right to me....

what am I missing here?

sudo iotedge check

```
sudo iotedge check

Configuration checks (aziot-identity-service)
---------------------------------------------
√ keyd configuration is well-formed - OK
× certd configuration is well-formed - Error
    certd's configuration file is not well-formed.
√ tpmd configuration is well-formed - OK
× identityd configuration is well-formed - Error
    identityd's configuration file is not well-formed.
‼ daemon configurations up-to-date with config.toml - Warning
    /etc/aziot/keyd/config.d/00-super.toml does not exist.
    Did you run 'aziotctl config apply'?
√ host time is close to reference time - OK
√ keyd is running - OK
√ certd is running - OK
√ tpmd is running - OK
√ identityd is running - OK
√ read all preloaded key pairs from the Keys Service - OK
√ ensure all preloaded certificates match preloaded private keys with the same ID - OK

Connectivity checks (aziot-identity-service)
--------------------------------------------

Configuration checks
--------------------
× aziot-edged configuration is well-formed - Error
    Error running check: The IoT Edge daemon's configuration file is not well-formed.
‼ configuration up-to-date with config.toml - Warning
    /etc/aziot/edged/config.d/00-super.toml does not exist.
    Did you run 'iotedge config apply'?
√ aziot-edge package is up-to-date - OK
√ DNS server - OK
√ production readiness: logs policy - OK

Connectivity checks
-------------------
12 check(s) succeeded.
2 check(s) raised warnings. Re-run with --verbose for more details.
3 check(s) raised errors. Re-run with --verbose for more details.
26 check(s) were skipped due to errors from other checks. Re-run with --verbose for more details.
```

- 

I get some errors above:

```
certd configuration is well-formed - Error certd's configuration file is not well-formed.

identityd configuration is well-formed - Error identityd's configuration file is not well-formed.

‼ daemon configurations up-to-date with config.toml - Warning /etc/aziot/keyd/config.d/00-super.toml does not exist.

× aziot-edged configuration is well-formed - Error Error running check: The IoT Edge daemon's configuration file is not well-formed.
```

‼ configuration up-to-date with config.toml - Warning
/etc/aziot/edged/config.d/00-super.toml does not exist.

What am I missing here?

I hope somebody can help?

Comment: Are you using connection string in config.toml? If yes,  does it have a `=` at the end?

Comment: No - We are using DPS provisioning with symmetric key: 

## DPS provisioning with symmetric key
[provisioning]
source = "dps"
global_endpoint = "https://global.azure-devices-provisioning.net"
id_scope = "0nexxx08F"

[provisioning.attestation]
method = "symmetric_key"
registration_id = "1exxxyy5"

symmetric_key = { value = "4p21DGrdUcN4+c0xxxxxxIsw3qIg0yZ62HVyyNw=" }

Comment: Seems like a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

The global_endpoint is missing the **https://** and make sure Toml registration ID matches the DPS registration ID.